# Calling second set of multithread functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, queue, python-multithreading

I have four functions, two of which are called to return a command, and another two which take the command and execute another function. I need function 1 & 2 and 3 & 4 to run simultaneously (ie, 1 and 2 at the same time, then 3 and 4 at the same time). I am currently using threading and queue modules in order to run the first two functions on multithreading.

My code looks like this:

```
import queue as q
import threading

def function_1(queue,var):
   *do something*
    queue.put(value_1)

def function_2(queue,var):
   *do something*
    queue.put(value_2)

def function_3(value):
   *do something w/ value*

def function_4(value):
   *do something w/ value*

queue_1 = q.Queue()
thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=function_1, args = (queue_1, int)
queue_2 = q.Queue()
thread_2 = threading.Thread(target=function_2, args = (queue_2, int)

thread_1.start()
thread_2.start()
thread_1.join()
thread_2.join()

value_1 = queue_1.get()
value_2 = queue_2.get()
```

Now I need to pass `value_1` and `value_2` to `function_3` and `function_4` respectively (also need these to run as close to simultaneously as possible), but I don't need to return anything from these functions. So can I simply call

```
 thread_3 = threading.Thread(target=function_3,args=(value_1)
 thread_4 = threading.Thread(target=function_4,args=(value_2)
 thread_3.start()
 thread_4.start()
 thread_3.join()
 thread_4.join()
```

It may seem like a straightforward question, but I guess I'm mostly confused on what's actually going on inside the computer. Is there anything I need to be aware of anything going on with `thread_1` and `thread_2` once those are completed before calling new threads for `function_3` and `function_4`?

Comment: There's nothing you need to be aware of. Why do you ask? Is there something not working?

Comment: @marineau No, but I've read a lot of instances where users have been writing multiprocess functions in python, but the functions aren't actually running concurrently. I just wanted to make sure that this is being done properly, and whether calling new threads in the manner I have (3/4 after 1/2) is the correct route of doing so.

Comment: It sounds you may be confusing multiprocessing and multithreading. The problem with the latter is that threads don't really run concurrently in Python except when one of them is waiting for I/O to complete because of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)—which was designed precisely to prevent it. With multiprocessing, each process has its own copy of the interpreter, but runs in a separate memory-space which makes sharing date between them more difficult and imposes a lot of overhead to overcome.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the clarification. So in my example above, am I not truly running my functions concurrently?

Comment: Not unless the threads are doing I/O (or calling some extension written in another language like C, one other case I just remembered). For tasks that are mostly doing computations of some kind, multiprocessing would allow actual concurrency, however the overhead of doing so may cancel out any speed gains obtained from being able to do so.